# cancel or hide input box in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which asks for an input between 1-3 using an `InputBox` which then runs a code depending on what input it is given. The problem i have is that i don't need that `InputBox` anymore, as the work i intend to do only uses one input which is 3.I tried removing the input box and just inserting 3 there but then the code doesnt do anything. I then tried to insert a default value in the box, but it still appears and needs me to click enter which is what i am trying to avoid. Pls how should i go about this problem.

**My Code**

```
Function GetTypeFile() As Integer

    Dim strInput As String, strMsg As String
    Dim Default

    choice = 0
    While (choice < 1 Or choice > 3)
        Default = "3"

        strMsg = "Type in the kind of entities to create (1 for points, 2 for points and splines, 3 for points, splines and loft):"
        strInput = InputBox(Prompt:=strMsg, _
                    Title:="User Info", Default:=3, XPos:=2000, YPos:=2000)

        'Validation of the choice
        choice = CInt(strInput)
        If (choice < 1 Or choice > 3) Then
            MsgBox "Invalid value: must be 1, 2 or 3"
        End If
    Wend
    GetTypeFile = choice

End Function
```

Comment: what do you want to have instead of the `InputBox` , if you allways put `3` what is the point ? the `GetTypeFile` will allways be `3`.

Comment: That is the problem, when i try to eliminate the `InputBox` the code then does not do anything. and when i tried assigning the value to the `GetTypeFile` directly, it still doesnt work..

Comment: so what are you trying this code to do? how do you want to enter the input of 1 to 3 ?

Comment: Each input depending whether it is 1,2 or 3 leads to a procedure that is supposed to open a CATfile in CATIA. I also want to try running the code from CATIA VBA directly without having to open the excel file and clicking run in excel  file or typing in the `inputbox` @ShaiRado

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns the value to wherever it's called, so you could just use:

```
Function GetTypeFile() As Integer
    GetTypeFile = 3
End Function
```

or just replace any calls to the function with the number `3`.

So rather than something like:

```
Sub Test()
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "MyFileName", GetTypeFile
End Sub
```

You'd have:

```
Sub Test()
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "MyFileName", 3
End
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried what you said, but when i try to run it, it doesnt do anything. The procedure is supposed to lead to it opening a CATfile in CATIA. I also want to try running the code from CATIA VBA directly without having to open the excel file and clicking run in excel  file or typing in the inputbox .

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your reply. I just understood what to do, by setting the variable which is dependent on the value in the `inputbox` to 3 instead of it being `TypeDocument=GetTypeFile` it is now `TypeDocument=3` directly..I think that is what you all had been trying to say all the while. Thank you again.